# How to prevent scrollview from scrolling on adding new view to the content layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have a LinearLayout inside a scrollview, When i add new content to the LinearLayout scrollview scrolls to that content and then jumps back to top.
How do i prevent this i.e. I want the scrollview to stay at the current position irrespective of addition or removal of new content.
I've tried

1. Setting descendantFocusability to blocksDescendants
2. Diable scrollview before adding new views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `OnSizeChanged` events of the `LinearLayout` by making your own LinearLayout and overriding `protected void onSizeChanged`. Determine the difference in oldh and h, and then `scrollview.setScrollY` to compensate for the difference.